# Why in created dataset in tensorflow Labels showed with shape and datatype information?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, dataset, label

I am new to Tensorflow:
I want to create my own dataset:

```
labels = ['N', 'N', 'N', 'A', 'A']

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir , labels = labels,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for images, labels in train_ds.take(1):
  for i in range(2):
    ax = plt.subplot(2, 2, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype('uint8'))
    plt.title(labels[i])
    plt.axis('off')
```

why when I plot the images the labels printed this way and not just label name?

Comment: _why when I plot the images the labels printed this way and not just label name?_ - what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate a dataset you get `tf.Tensor` objects, and when you pass that directly to `plt.title` it gets converted to a string which produces that result. If you want the contents of the tensor you can use `.numpy()`, as you do with the images:

```py
plt.title(labels[i].numpy())
```

EDIT: The `b` prefix is because TensorFlow strings actually correspond to Python bytearrays (which, when represented as a string, get the prefix). If you want to get an actual `str`, so you do not see that, you can use `.decode()`:

```py
plt.title(labels[i].numpy().decode())
```

Comment: that almost works but still print " b'N' ", How can I remove that " b"

Comment: @MaryamKia Right, forgot about that, I edited the answer.